# How to Install a local .rpm file by automatically downloading/installing other dependencies

Tags: rpm, yum, rhel7

Now there are multiple variations of this question, but none apply to me.

I want to install a locally downloaded `.rpm` file and any other dependencies that would be required while running this install, automatically.

The question is very specific to locally downloaded, so please do not suggest running yum-downloader for a known package name. Nothing is known. I discovered a nice `.rpm`, downloaded it, and now want to install it.

*Detailed example:*

My system already has `polycoreutils-python-2.5-11`. If I install using yum, this is the highest version I get. However, I got a **locally downloaded** upgrade file which is even higher version `polycoreutils-python-2.5-24 ... .rpm`

When I try to install this, of course, it complains about new missing deps, namely, `polycore-utils` and `setools-lib`. I have them installed too, but older versions. So I can go download the needed new `.rpm` files.

But I can't repeat this process for as many dependencies discovered step by step. What's the best way to install a **locally downloaded package**, and its required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You yust need to use `yum` to install that package you downloaded. `yum` will then manage the dependencies for you:

```
Yum install /path/to/downloaded.rpm
```

If `yum` cannot find the dependencies you need, you should tell `yum` where he can find them: add the repository where he can find them.

**EDIT**
Multiple remarks concerning the installation of externally downloaded packages.

- If you can; stick with the versions that are available in the official repositories; or in *related* repositories (like `epel` for centos or `packman` for opensuse).
- Once you start downloading yourself `rpms` from the internet; try to stay as close as possible to your os and version of your os. The further you go from your os-version; the more probable that you will get dependency errors. It is very well possible that you will have to start upgrading so many packages that you are close to doing a manual distribution upgrade; which obviously is quite risky.
- If you find a package that was repackaged by someone for your os and os-version; you can simply add his repository to your `yum`; even if it is just for the time to install your rpm (you can disable or remove that repository afterwards). Be careful when adding this repository that you don't start upgrading too many of your packages without need; because then you might again run into issues if this is not an officially maintained repository.
- If you don't find a repository that you can temporarily add to `yum`, the only solution that remains is manually downloading all dependencies into a local directory and then running `yum install directory/*rpm`. Note that - if you are lucky - you might find the rpms you depend on next to where you downloaded the rpm you want to install. Otherwise http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3 is a very nice place to start searching.

Comment: No it doesn't. It says: `error: Failed dependencies: xyz > 1.2.3 needed by downloaded`

Comment: @KingJulian I edited my answer with multiple remarks that may help you on your way. Good luck.